# Failed to load jxbrowser in plain OSGi enviroment

Tags: jxbrowser

I've been using jxbrpowser 6.2 with a trial license. Trying to load it in OSGi enviroment generates the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
   (...)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$39/30523883.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractorException: Failed to extract chromium binaries into C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Temp\jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.6.2
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractor.extract(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.create(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC$a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The /chromium-windows.zip resource cannot be found in JAR files.
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ZIPExtractor.extract(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.e.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 19 more
```

I can successfully load jxbrowser in the non-OSGi environment, as well as in OSGi environment when resources are already extracted.

Is there any way to make jxbrowser successfully extracts the resources from the jar?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like you don't have a correct OSGI bundle for JxBrowser. As far as I know jxbrowser supports OSGI bundle distribution, you can simply install it into your OSGI container.

Alternatively you can create your own bundle with which is only exports JxBrowser public API, but contains JxBrowser libraries you need. You can automate it with Felix bundle plugin for example http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

In order to make such a bundle working you will need to initialize an temporary browser instance (just create a browser component) inside bundle activator. So that chromium binaries will be extracted when bundle is installed in your OSGi container.